# How can I use data-toggle in a form button?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a modal box inside a form button as above. But when I click on button then a modal box is appeared instead of redirecting to `action="email/index.php"`. How can I redirect to `action="email/index.php"` and use `data-toggle` at the same time?

Here is my code:

```
<form name="enq" method="post" action="email/index.php" onsubmit="return validation();">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""
           class="input-block-level" placeholder="Name" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""
           class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email" />
    <br /><br />
    <textarea rows="11" name="message" id="message"
              class="input-block-level" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
    <br /><br />

    <div class="actions">
      <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" id="submitButton"
             class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
             title="Click here to submit your message!" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you that use ajax tech, with this you can go to the server 
catch the data and so open your modal

```
$('form#enq').on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();// prevents the default redirections
     // store reference to the form
     var bk_this = $(this);

    // grab the url from the form element
    var url = bk_this.attr('action');//it contains your url: email/index.php

    //Obteniendo la data del form
    var dataToSend = bk_this.serialize();

    var fo_proccess = function (data){
        // here you can open your model box manually
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }

    $.post( url, dataToSend, fo_proccess,'json');

});
```